# flask restful: how to give multiple arguments to get methhod of any Api using flask restful?

Tags: python, flask-restful

the following is my code for get method:

```
def get(self, ques_no, i):
    j=i
    opt_dict = {}
    for ques in session.query(Options.optn).filter(Options.q_no == ques_no)[j:j+2]:
        opt_dict.update({i:ques.optn})
        i=i+1
    return jsonify(opt_dict)
```

api.add_resource(store_option, '/option/&&', endpoint = 'option_id')

i need to pass to arguments to my get method to access the database. but i'm not able pass to arguments. how can i do that??
any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Are the arguments you need to pass specific to each request, fixed?

Comment: But you are already passing arguments like `ques_no` and `i`, no? I don't understand your question, then.

Comment: This way is not correct. These two parameters are to be received using http get request

Comment: I'm getting error here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From modifying my own code, something like this should work.

Start by defining a class like this:

```
class DBAccessor(Resource):                                                                                                                      
    def put(self, ques_no, i):      
        ...                             
        return 'ok'
```

Now connect it like this:

```
app = Flask('wasp')                                                          
api = Api(app)                                                                  

api.add_resource(                                                               
    DBAccessor,                                                
    '/option/<ques_no>/<i>')
```

Comment: Type error: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'q_no'

Comment: IDK, it works for me. I suggest you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the error you got.